# Pattern matching and Plus, Times, Power etc

Tags: pattern-matching

Could you please describe the behavior of this code:

```
p[d[1, 2], d[1, 2]] /. p[a___, Plus[b_], c___] -> {{a}, {b}, {c}}
```

> {{}, {d[1, 2]}, {d[1, 2]}}

Why this pattern matches Plus when the expression doesn't have any Plus functions?

Also, how can I check that all arguments of function p[] don't have any Plus, Times and Power?

Comment: Take a look at `p[a___, Plus[b_], c___]` alone

Comment: And then after that, look into `HoldPattern`